# RFC/Standard for Web-Polling of Long-Running Commands

Tags: ajax, stream, web-standards, rfc

We've got an old web UI wherein part of it polls an appliance via AJAX to get the results of long-running commands, so the progress and stdout/stderr of the commands can be displayed to the user.  It just does a request every few seconds to get whatever new output is available; no rocket science here.

Now, years later, we're refactoring all its web UIs.  That got me wondering, *"surely others do this kind of thing all the time - there's got to be an RFC for it"*.  I went digging around but came up empty handed.

**Is there already a standard** that describes a popular manner for doing this short-polling? (and what is/are these standards?)

It would be implementation independent, just describing the protocol, as a subset of HTTP.  For example, are requests done with GET or POST or PUT; what HTTP status codes are used to indicate job status (queued, running, aborted, done, etc), or is this done with response headers, and what name was given to these headers; or do we send client info in query params or headers or body content, ...?

There's so many different ways this can be done, I thought it would be nice to do it the common way.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is done by a set of standards-based technologies. Seems the term AJAX, for an existing web application model, was coined by Adaptive Path as a shorthand for Asynchronous JavaScript + XML.

see: [Ajax: A New Approach to Web Applications](http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications/)

> Ajax isn’t a technology. It’s really several technologies, each flourishing in its own right, coming together in powerful new ways. Ajax incorporates:
>
> - standards-based presentation using XHTML and CSS;
> - dynamic display and interaction using the Document Object Model;
> - data interchange and manipulation using XML and XSLT;
> - asynchronous data retrieval using XMLHttpRequest;
> - and JavaScript binding everything together.